# Why can't I save any databases with filenames larger than 8 characters? MS_Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am using this code, but for some reason, any names larger than 8 characters, get cut off:

```
Dim SaveName As String
Dim CurrentDate As Date

CurrentDate = Now

SaveName = InputBox("Save Database as..", "Save as..", CurrentDate)

DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
acExport, _
"dBase IV", _
"C:\Data\PLC_MOBZ\Test\export", _
acTable, _
"DB_Total", _
SaveName, _
False
```

As you can understand, even when nothing is entered, the default name would be:

```
"22-2-2013 14:42:44"
```

which needs to be longer than 8 characters.

Comment: Have you done a `Debug.Print` after setting **SaveName** to ensure it reads as you would like, as a side note however you can't include `:` characters in a windows file name, perhaps that is upsetting it, try setting **CurrentDate** like this `CurrentDate = Format(Now,"DD-M-YYYY HHNNSS")`

Comment: So, are you trying to save your database as a dBase IV file?

Comment: @Matt Donnan, I am using your format, howver that does not seem to change anything to the 8 character max size

Comment: This seems to be a Microsoft problem: support.microsoft.com/kb/240748 There are other ways than transferdatabase, or you can just export blah and rename.

Comment: dBase 4 was a db system from the 8.3 ms-dos filename days, so the names of .dbf, .ndx, .mdx files must have a maximum filename of 8 characters (with a maximum extension of 3 characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dbase standard. The "dir" or "folder" is database name, and the files inside are the tables.  As a result you cannot and should not create tables outside of the dBase format.

If you create anything else then those dBase programs will not be able to read or find the files which in turn represent tables.

So both the folder name and the file names need to remain 8.3 format, and ALSO should not contain spaces. So this is not a Microsoft problem but is a dBase standard.

You can certainly break this rule by after creating the file you can re-name the file. You can do this outside of Access, or use the VBA "name" command

Eg:

```
Name  "oldFileName" as  "newFileName"
```